# Change date axis ticks in Altair to show years

Tags: timestamp, data-visualization, altair

I'm building a chart in Altair.

The x axis is a temporal type with dates spanning years.
I would like it to show the years. But instead, it is showing just the months without indications of the year. How can I tell Altair to display the year ticks instead or in addition to the months?

Ideally, it would show a cycle of tick labels like "2015, June, 2016, June, 2017, June,...".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the date format using `axis.format`. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': pd.date_range('2015', periods=48, freq='M')
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_tick().encode(
  alt.X('date:T', axis=alt.Axis(format="%Y %B"))
)
```

[image]

The format codes are described in the [d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) package.

Comment: Thanks! How can I edit the periodicity of the ticks?
And what if I want to have an alternating formatting ?
Ie I want January of each year to be formated as `"%Y"`, while I want June of each year to be formatted as `"%M"`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.interactive()` on the chart? The date format will change according to how you zoom in or out on the chart, giving the format you're looking for at some point along the scale. The only other thing I can think of would be using a custom tick column as the x-axis, with `%Y %b` at the appropriate points and blanks otherwise, but I couldn't quite get that to work myself.

Answer (score 2):

To get one tick per year, you can use: `axis=alt.Axis(tickCount="year")`.

See the [doc](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html).